# Access javascript function from code behind

Tags: c#, javascript

I have a function inside a document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function test1() {
        alert('successful');
    }
});
```

Now in the Code behind (C#) I have this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page),"Con121", "test1();", true);
```

This does not popup with an alert... But works fine if I take it out of the ready function.
I need this to work in the ready.

I have even tried doing this with no success:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.test1 function test1() {
        alert('successful');
    }
});
```

Comment: Why are you trying to declare a function *inside* another function? That just looks wierd! You say you `need this to work in the ready` - please can you elaborate on this statement to explain *why* you have to do it this way?

Comment: You need to declare it globally.

Comment: Your second example is not valid JavaScript syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
var test1;

$(document).ready(function () {
    test1 = function () {
        alert('successful');
    }
});
```

The problem here is scoping.  Since you're declaring your function `test1` from within another function (`ready`), the startup script you're creating from the code-behind won't be able to access it from outside of the `ready` function.

Also, you need to make sure that your start up script is being fired after `jQuery.ready` because otherwise you might try to invoke an unassigned variable.

Finally, if the function doesn't need to be specifically declared from withing `ready`, simply move it out of there altogether so that both function declaration and assignment will exist in the global scope.

Comment: Worth noting that the JS document ready will be called AFTER the code behind Page_Load so could cause another hiccup.

Answer (score 0):

(Part of) your problem is that your `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` call puts the `test1();` call somewhere in your page's HTML where it is executed immediately, but the `$(document).ready(function () { ... });` wrapping the *definition* of `test1` means the function doesn't exist to be called until *after* the page, including the call, has already been loaded.

There's no reason to wait for the document to be ready to define your function, so why not just define it straight out?

Alternatively, why not remove the `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` and put the call `test1();` immediately after the definition? This will call it as soon as the page has finished loading:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function test1() {
        alert('successful');
    }
    test1();
});
```